# Navigation Drawer pattern material design

Tags: android, material-design

Google just posted in their blog [a post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2014/10/material-design-on-android-checklist.html) discussing best practices for implementing the material design. It says:

> If the app uses a navigation drawer, it follows the newer material design interactions and styling (Figure 7). The drawer appears in front of the app bar. It also appears semitransparent behind the status bar.

But, if you look at how it is implemented in apps like Google Play Store and Inbox by Gmail, the navigation drawer is located below the Action Bar (Toolbar).

[image]

However, apps like Play Newsstand and Pushbullet use their drawer above the toolbar, as recommended.
So, which one should I use?

One side note, if I should place the drawer above the toolbar, why did Google implement the animation in the hamburger icon at all(ActionBarDrawerToggle)?

Comment: Do what the Material guidelines say, not what Inbox does. Put your drawer above the action bar.

Comment: So why the animation ActionBarDrawerToggle? Even in Play Newsstand you can see the icon changing.

Comment: Likely belongs on ux.stackexchange.com, or possibly http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That is exactly my question. If I should place the drawer above the toolbar, why the only way in new design library to add hamburger icon is the DrawerToggle WITH animation? (If I don't want the animation I have to put an icon manually). Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the version from the Material Specs and display your left drawer over the bar.

The **width** of the `NavigationDrawer` on Inbox is also incorrect:

> The width of the side nav is equal to the width of the screen minus the height of the action bar, or in this case 56dp from the right edge of the screen.
>
> Mobile: Width = screen width - app bar height
>
> Desktop: Max width for the left nav is 400dp. The right nav can vary depending on content.

The animation also shows when you pull out the right drawer, which should be displayed below the drawer. Further more, your drawer can be (semi-)translucent.